# gulp не встает! выдает ошибки

Tags: javascript

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at requireOrImport (C:\Users\shura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11)      
    at execute (C:\Users\shura\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:37:3)
```

Comment: Это на что?????

Comment: В английской версии вопроса предлагают добавить `"type": "module"` в `package.json`. Есть еще [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138423/discussion-on-question-by-stranger-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outs), посмотрите, может там что то есть.

Comment: в терминале vscode выдает ошибки

Comment: спасибо большое за подсказску!